# Distribute individuals to relevant mentors as evenly as possible

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I'm working on a site that needs a matching feature, but I'm wondering if there's a mathematical model that already tackles what I'm trying to do.

Users belong to Mentors, but they can choose their Mentor. Out of all Mentors, only a handful will be presented to a given User. This handful can change per User. Mentors have biographies, so that can influence the decision of Users.

The goal is to have an even distribution of users per Mentor within a certain timeframe, while still giving the User as much choice as possible.

**What is the best model that fits these requirements and constraints?**

The stream of new Users and new Mentors coming in is relatively steady.

Comment: So you want each Mentor to have a roughly equal number of Users?

Comment: You can do something probabilistic, where as usage of Mentor increases (# of his mentees goes up relative to others), probability of him being in the pool presented goes down - or deterministically, rank all mentors from highest usage to lowest and draw new batch to be presented from the bottom of the list only (bottom - lowest usage)